# How to limit memory consumption in Esper Window

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper, nesper

I have the following query window in my application. I want an update on when the Employee event is coming the first time (a new Employee ) OR if there is any update for an existing Employee. My application is getting a lot of updates and I suspect the below Window is not keeping only the last two records in memory and due to that memory uses increase with time.
Is there any way I can ensure that only last two records are available in Window?

```
@name('stmtUpdateEmployee') select * from Employee#groupwin(empId)#length(2)
    where
    prev(1, age) <> age OR
    prev(1, dept) <> dept OR
    prev(1, address) <> address OR
    prev(1, empId) is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect the below Window is not keeping only the last two records in
> memory and due to that memory uses increase with time

Your suspicion is correct! There will be more than the last two records in memory ... depending on the data, a lot more.

As mentioned in section [Esper Reference 5.6.8](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.8.0/reference-esper/html_single/#epl-group-by-versus-view), the `groupwin(empId)` line in the select clause ...

```
select * from Employee#groupwin(empId)#length(2)
```

creates a separate data window per key value, and the query planner creates a hash index on `Employee`, essentially resulting in holding onto all the employee events that have a unique `empId`.

So this will **grow with the number of unique employees** ... there will be at least 2 * the number of unique employees events (since this is a length of 2, the latest employee event and the previous employee event are in memory.)

Comment: Hi, should we say that there could be more than 2 events present in memory for same key even we are looking only latest 2?